# What is the best naming style for objects in class instances?

Tags: scala, naming-conventions

http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html suggests that all objects are camelCase with a capital first letter except when attempting to mimic a package or a function. But what about mimicing a `val`?

```
class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  object myBox extends javax.swing.Box(javax.swing.BoxLayout.X_AXIS) {
    object myLabel extends javax.swing.JLabel {
      import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
      object myFont extends java.awt.Font(Map(java.awt.font.TextAttribute.FOREGROUND -> java.awt.Color.RED).asJava)
      setFont(myFont)
    }
    add(myLabel)
  }
  add(myBox)
  setSize(100, 60)
}
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val myFrame = new MyFrame
    myFrame.myBox.myLabel.setText("Hello, World!")
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
    myFrame.setVisible(true)
  }
}
```

Or

```
class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  object MyBox extends javax.swing.Box(javax.swing.BoxLayout.X_AXIS) {
    object MyLabel extends javax.swing.JLabel {
      import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
      object MyFont extends java.awt.Font(Map(java.awt.font.TextAttribute.FOREGROUND -> java.awt.Color.RED).asJava)
      setFont(MyFont)
    }
    add(MyLabel)
  }
  add(MyBox)
  setSize(100, 60)
}
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val myFrame = new MyFrame
    myFrame.MyBox.MyLabel.setText("Hello, World!") // Seems a bit weird to me
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
    myFrame.setVisible(true)
  }
}
```

Which one is better?

Comment: Since there are only two choices proffered, the proper adjective is "better," not "best." And yes, English grammar is all we can fall back on here...

Comment: Come for the Scala, spend 15 minutes improving your knowledge of English grammar. Thank you, @RandallSchulz.

Answer (score -2):

Just use camelCase  for package objects.
for embedded objects in class use Upper camelCase.

Comment: Why would I? Any reasoning behind your statements?